# Example Of Kogito User Service & Connector

Tags: bpmn, kogito

As far as I know in Kogito, user task in BPMN require external user service and connector to supply user/group information. However I can't find suitable reference or example or document(Or, i can't understand how it work). Can anyone elaborate or provide sample how to use my own user/group in the workflow approval?

Answer (score 0):

In Kogito BPMN, you can use the Task User Service integrated with Keycloak to achieve what you're looking for. Have you tried what is described in this doc https://docs.jboss.org/kogito/release/latest/html_single/#proc-task-console-security_kogito-developing-process-services?

Comment: Yes I did explore about that, and that is not short and clear solution answer, beside the example over complex and involve more then 10++ container created connect to each others. My expectation is how to use different restapi value demonstrate the whole user task process. 
* I have rough ideal after some try and error, seems we submit parameter user=x, it will filter task belong to user x only. same like group.